# If Condition not match in php

Tags: php, laravel

We have an issue with PHP developing if condition how to match condition

```
$individualStock = DB::table('inventory')->leftjoin('inventory_detail','inventory_detail.inventory_ref_id','=','inventory.inventory_ref_id')
            ->selectRaw('inventory.*')
            ->whereIn('inventory_detail.attribute_id', [$attributeid])
            ->where(DB::raw('(select count from `inventory_detail` where `inventory_detail`.`attribute_id` in ('.$attributeid.') and `inventory_ref_id`= "'.$inventory->inventory_ref_id.'")'),'=',$count)
            ->where('inventory.inventory_ref_id','=',$inventory->inventory_ref_id)              
            ->groupBy('inventory_detail.inventory_ref_id')
            ->get();
```

I match condition with some issue with condition

```
$individualStack = Collection form sql empty array
$countValue = count($individualStock) // 0


                if(count($individualStock) > 0  ){ // 0 > 0 // FIX condition
              echo "Why here print Hello";die();                
                $inventory_ref_id[] = $individualStock[0]->inventory_ref_id;
                $stockIn += $individualStock[0]->stock;
            } else {
echo "Why"
}
```

Fix issue $inventory_ref_id[] for all over code in foreach problem has solved

Please help me, How can I do fix this condition?

Comment: What exactly the problem is?

Comment: update `if(count($individualStock) > 0  ){ ... }` with `if($countValue){  ... }`

Comment: Sorry guys, working fine foreach loop declaring code, we find out issue. Thanks for summit answers @Bram and Praffula

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To count the records you should use the `count()` method.

```
$countValue = $individualStock->count();
```

See the [Laravel documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-count) about this.

If you just want to check if the result is empty, use the `isEmpty()` method instead.

```
if ($individualStock->isEmpty()) {
    // ....
}
```

Comment: We have tested all method but is not working in laravel version 5.4, please update

Comment: The count method should also work in Laravel 5.4. Please update your question with the new code where you use the count method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are getting a collection so the correct [method](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-isempty) will be

`$individualStack ->isEmpty()`

or

`$individualStack->isNotEmpty()`

Comment: We have tested all method but is not working in laravel version 5.4, please update

Comment: @SonuKumar  It should work in 5.4 too, post the exact code you are trying.

Answer (score 0):

you can use just one function

```
if($individualStock->isEmpty())
```